# Yii - Auth issues: Can't login via Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, yii

I'm facing really strange issue with my app powered by Yii framework.

Basically, I can't login any user using Google Chrome (v.12, Linux 64bit).

I'm able to login via FF, IE, Opera but not via Chrome.

I presume that there's something wrong with session/cookies, but what? Does anybody faced similar issue before?

I store sessions in db. My config:

```
'session' => array(
            'autoStart' => true,
            'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
            'sessionTableName' => 'Sessions'
        ),
'user'=>array(
            'class' => 'WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin' => false,
        ),
'authManager'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
),
```

**Edit**
I noticed funny thing: when I allow users to autoLogin via cookie by setting `'allowAutoLogin' => true,` it works. But, when the checkbox is not checked it doesn't. Weird.

**Edit II**
Tried to downgrade/upgrade my Chrome installation to make sure it's related to the browser. The issue still exists.

Comment: Are you logging in through ajax? If so, is there any error in the console?

Comment: @Kor - Not using AJAX. No errors in console, log files. After submitting button I'm just redirected to index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.

There was some incompatibility issues with yii-debug-toolbar extension. After disabling it, everything works perfectly.